# Use canonical tag with multidomains

Tags: domains, rel-canonical

The `canonical` link type should be used to avoid duplicate content within a page.

Is there a way to apply it to content from another domain?

Comment: Do you mean within a site (instead of "within a page")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 6596 [says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-3) that the `canonical` URI may

> Exist on a different hostname or domain.

---

Google Search [documents](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) that they support it, e.g.:

> **Addressing syndicated content.** If you syndicate your content for publication on other domains, you want to consolidate page ranking to your preferred URL.